# Possible ways to depth scan skin wounds using iPhone

Tags: opencv, stereo-3d, medical

I was wondering about the accuracy of stereo vision on a smaller scale, I am currently doing a project on the measurement of wound depths and I was trying to see if anyone knew if the use of computer vision libraries like openCV was accurate enough to measure/map small cuts/wounds in the skin. I am limited by the use of an iPhone 13 pro to capture images for processing.

I tried to find similar uses of stereo vision but have only seen uses on a more macro scale. I've found that usually medical scans use expensive laser based scanning techniques to measure to surface of the skin but I'm trying to find alternative and cost effective ways that could possibly work.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is not much likely that you will be able to  measure small cuts/wounds depth. What i think is possible is to detect/segment it in 2d image. Stereo and even the LiDAR from iphone pro have precision errors much above 2mm (which i think is the depth of what you want to measure).

Take a look here:

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6/are-computer-stereo-vision-techniques-appropriate-for-sub-millimetre-measurement

here:

[Accuracy in depth estimation - Stereo Vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764579/accuracy-in-depth-estimation-stereo-vision)

and here:

https://www.flir.com/support-center/iis/machine-vision/knowledge-base/accuracy-of-stereo-vision-camera-disparity-depth-calculations/